# Java using contains function to match string object ignore capital case?

Tags: java, contains, case-insensitive

I want that the contain function should return true even if the following are in capital letters

```
    List<String> pformats= Arrays.asList("odt","ott","oth","odm","sxw","stw","sxg","doc","dot","xml","docx","docm","dotx","dotm","doc","wpd","wps","rtf","txt","csv","sdw","sgl","vor","uot","uof","jtd","jtt","hwp","602","pdb","psw","ods","ots","sxc","stc","xls","xlw","xlt","xlsx","xlsm","xltx","xltm","xlsb","wk1","wks","123","dif","sdc","vor","dbf","slk","uos","pxl","wb2","odp","odg","otp","sxi","sti","ppt","pps","pot","pptx","pptm","potx","potm","sda","sdd","sdp","vor","uop","cgm","bmp","dxf","emf","eps","met","pbm","pct","pcd","pcx","pgm","plt","ppm","psd","ras","sda","sdd","sgf","sgv","svm","tgs","tif","tiff","vor","wmf","xbm","xpm","jpg","jpeg","gif","png","pdf","log");

if(pformats.contains(extension)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Note: A HashSet is better for lookups: Set<String> pformats= new HashSet(Arrays.asList(....));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Set is a better choice for a lookup.

```
private static final Set<String> P_FORMATS = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "odt,ott,oth,odm,sxw,stw,sxg,doc,dot,xml,docx,docm,dotx,dotm,doc,wpd,wps,rtf,txt,csv,sdw,sgl,vor,uot,uof,jtd,jtt,hwp,602,pdb,psw,ods,ots,sxc,stc,xls,xlw,xlt,xlsx,xlsm,xltx,xltm,xlsb,wk1,wks,123,dif,sdc,vor,dbf,slk,uos,pxl,wb2,odp,odg,otp,sxi,sti,ppt,pps,pot,pptx,pptm,potx,potm,sda,sdd,sdp,vor,uop,cgm,bmp,dxf,emf,eps,met,pbm,pct,pcd,pcx,pgm,plt,ppm,psd,ras,sda,sdd,sgf,sgv,svm,tgs,tif,tiff,vor,wmf,xbm,xpm,jpg,jpeg,gif,png,pdf,log".split(","));

if(P_FORMATS.contains(extension.toLowerCase())){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Will not work. You can't overwrite the contains, **BUT:** You can us the following code:

```
List<String> pformats= Arrays.asList("odt","ott","oth","odm","sxw","stw","sxg","doc","dot","xml","docx","docm","dotx","dotm","doc","wpd","wps","rtf","txt","csv","sdw","sgl","vor","uot","uof","jtd","jtt","hwp","602","pdb","psw","ods","ots","sxc","stc","xls","xlw","xlt","xlsx","xlsm","xltx","xltm","xlsb","wk1","wks","123","dif","sdc","vor","dbf","slk","uos","pxl","wb2","odp","odg","otp","sxi","sti","ppt","pps","pot","pptx","pptm","potx","potm","sda","sdd","sdp","vor","uop","cgm","bmp","dxf","emf","eps","met","pbm","pct","pcd","pcx","pgm","plt","ppm","psd","ras","sda","sdd","sgf","sgv","svm","tgs","tif","tiff","vor","wmf","xbm","xpm","jpg","jpeg","gif","png","pdf","log");
                            if(pformats.contains(extension.toLowerCase())){

}
```

This will make you extension to lowercase, and if within your Array are all extensions are already lowerCase, than it'll wokk.

Comment: As Peter Lawrey mentioned, a Set will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
extension.toLowerCase()
```

?

Although I'm not sure 100% sure what `contains()` method will do in this example. You might need to stick your extensions into a `Set`.

**Edit:** No it wont work as the contains method checks for the existence of a particular Object. Your string, even with the same value, is a different Object. So yes either a) override the contains method, e.g loop through the array and do a string comparison or b) simpler, use a Set.

**Edit 2:** Apparently it will work per comments below as ArrayList.contains() checks for equality (so you will get a string match), but this seems to disagree with the top voted answer that says it wont.

Comment: `contains()` is on `Collection` so it will work. It's just more efficient on a `Set`.

Comment: @artbristol: really? I just edited my answer to say the opposite. Not sure who's right!

Comment: @Richard Contains checks for equality, object identity. The javadoc for ArrayList says `Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).`.

Comment: The question was "How to ensure, that the contains()-method will use a lowercase comparision of two Strings" That will not work, expect you create a Deriferd Class, wich implements the contains()-method, But that is not a really good Idea. Your (and mine) Idea was to change the parameter provided to the contains-method. Thats more easier, than to derive a class.

Comment: @ckuetbach - yeah ok understood

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `List` of extensions into a regular expression, compile it with the `CASE_INSENSITVE` flag, and use that.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class Foo {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("odt|ott|oth|odm|sxw|stw|sxg|doc|dot|xml|docx|docm|dotx|dotm|doc|wpd|wps|rtf|txt|csv|sdw|sgl|vor|uot|uof|jtd|jtt|hwp|602|pdb|psw|ods|ots|sxc|stc|xls|xlw|xlt|xlsx|xlsm|xltx|xltm|xlsb|wk1|wks|123|dif|sdc|vor|dbf|slk|uos|pxl|wb2|odp|odg|otp|sxi|sti|ppt|pps|pot|pptx|pptm|potx|potm|sda|sdd|sdp|vor|uop|cgm|bmp|dxf|emf|eps|met|pbm|pct|pcd|pcx|pgm|plt|ppm|psd|ras|sda|sdd|sgf|sgv|svm|tgs|tif|tiff|vor|wmf|xbm|xpm|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|log", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        // Will be true
        System.out.println(p.matcher("bmp").matches());
        // Will be false
        System.out.println(p.matcher("quasar").matches());
    }
}
```

This would probably be easier to read/maintain if you build the regex programatically, but I've left that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If all your formats are lower case, then `toLowerCase` combined with a HashSet is the preferred solution.

If your formats are in mixed case (and shall stay this way, as you are using them for other things, too) you need a real case-insensitive comparison.

Then a TreeSet (or other SortedSet) with a case insensitive collator as the comparator will do. (It is not as fast as a HashSet, but will still be faster then the ArrayList (except for really small lists).)

Alternatively a HashSet variant using a custom hashCode and equals (or simply a normal HashSet on wrapper objects with a case insensitive implementation of equals and hashCode) would do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this extended List class:

```
private static class ListIgnoreCase<String> extends java.util.LinkedList {
       public ListIgnoreCase(Collection<String> c) {
           super();
           addAll(c);
       }
       public boolean containsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String toSearch) {
           for (Object element : this)
               if (java.lang.String.valueOf(element).equalsIgnoreCase(toSearch))
                   return true;

           return false;
       }
   }
```

Now you can call `asList` like this:

```
if(new ListIgnoreCase(Arrays.asList("odt","ott","oth","odm"))
      .containtsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IteracleUtils and Predicate from collections4 (apache).

```
List<String> pformats= Arrays.asList("odt","ott","oth","odm","sxw","stw","sxg","doc","dot","xml","docx","docm","dotx","dotm","doc","wpd","wps","rtf","txt","csv","sdw","sgl","vor","uot","uof","jtd","jtt","hwp","602","pdb","psw","ods","ots","sxc","stc","xls","xlw","xlt","xlsx","xlsm","xltx","xltm","xlsb","wk1","wks","123","dif","sdc","vor","dbf","slk","uos","pxl","wb2","odp","odg","otp","sxi","sti","ppt","pps","pot","pptx","pptm","potx","potm","sda","sdd","sdp","vor","uop","cgm","bmp","dxf","emf","eps","met","pbm","pct","pcd","pcx","pgm","plt","ppm","psd","ras","sda","sdd","sgf","sgv","svm","tgs","tif","tiff","vor","wmf","xbm","xpm","jpg","jpeg","gif","png","pdf","log");

Predicate<String> predicate  = (s) -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(s, "JPG");
if(IterableUtils.matchesAny(pformats, predicate))
    // do stuff
}
```

[org.apache.commons.collections4.IterableUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html)